# Tortoise SVN will work in this scenario or not?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a PLC based online program which is running on few machines. There are few people who work on those machines at different times. If there is a problem in the way the machines are working they edit and update the program accordingly.

What I need is software which will keep a watch on these updates and ask the person to fill in his id and a comment before he exits the code after updating.

Does Tortoise SVN have these options inside it or not? If it is available, how can I make one person admin?

Comment: what is "PLC based online program"?

Comment: means a code for omron plc is running on those machines for automation